# Understand the code of the smooth scroll script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm learning jquery and found a script for smooth scrolling on click, which works perfect, but I don't understand it and I want to understand the code and why does what it does:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

First I get that it begins with:
`$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click()`
this says that every time you click on something with a href link to a '#'

then

```
if(location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname)
```

I have no idea what is that

neither this:

```
var target = $(this.hash);
target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1)
```

what is ".hash"? and what about the '?'? and the ':'?

the rest I got it.

thanks!

Comment: `? :` are ternary operators - another way of doing `if{...}else{...}` `.hash` gets everything after `#` from the URL

Comment: read about javascript [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hash` is the string that follows the `#`. So in the url `index.html#path` the hash will be `path`. The `pathname` checks if it's under the same original hostname and page, so it's a URL that points to the same page and will be scroll, if it's another page, scroll has no sense.

Ternary operators are like `if()` statements but in shorthand:

```
var a = (b == 1) ? "b equal one" : "b not equal one";
```

It's the same as:

```
var a;
if(b == 1) {
   a = "b equal one";
}  else {
   a = "b not equal one";
}
```

Comment: and what about "if(location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname)"

Comment: I tell you: `The pathname checks if it's under the same original hostname and page, so it's a URL that points to the same page and will be scroll, if it's another page, scroll has no sense.`

Comment: Only one last thing,what is this? (/^\//,'')

Comment: Is a regular expression in the replace method, that means "*replace by nothing the first `/` ocurrence*". Then if a pathname is like this: `/my/path`, the final result will be `my/path`